# a simple excel command or a program that updates value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I would like to beg for my stupidity, bear with me, I am very new!

I will try to make it as clear as possible.

I want to create a excel program or possibly just do it with excel, that I can use for my business.

Let's say I have a customer that prepaid $100. He purchased $3 the first day and $8 the next day.

I would have a value of $100. I subtract $3 then the $100 would become $97. Then subtract $8 so it would become $89. So basically, it keeps updates the amount.

I couldn't figure how to do this in excel. Is there a way to allow this in excel? or do I have to make a excel workbook or excel template using commands?

I would love to get help from professionals!

Comment: Are you going to leave the values $3 and $8 in the worksheet?

Comment: I would love to but wouldn't that make the cells overload? Or is there a way around this to somehow leave the inputs as a trace?

Comment: Hmm, cells overload? A excel file (excel-2007) can take up to 1,048,576 rows of cells. I don't think that's a problem :) And I'm not sure what you mean by 'leave the inputs as a trace'. I would do it like this: Put the formula `=100-SUM(B:B)` in A1, then put all the purchases in cells B. So $3 goes in B1 and $8 goes in B2, and all subsequent purchases in following cells below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is the sort of thing you want:

[image: SO21809812 example]

This seems basically to be as described by @Jerry. C2 has an entered value and other values are entered in ColumnB. C4 onwards are simply the formula in C3 copied down to suit.